# Помогите разобраться с datepicker jquery пожалуйста друзья

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Доброго времени суток друзья! есть дефолтный input который вызывает datepicker при нажатии

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker-here">
```

и блок который выводит выбранную дату

```
<div class="selected-data">Дата Уборки: </div>
```

Не могу сделать так чтобы внутри inputа изначально была текущяя дата
и вторая проблема, когда человек выбирает определенную дату чтобы календарь закрывался и выбранная дата перешла в DIV с классом selected-data в виде текста например так: (16 апреля, 2021 в 8 вечера)

Comment: какой пикер-то? jquery-ui ?

Comment: вроде-бы air datepicker